# How can I use docker-compose in an AWS EC2 machine that has been started via Terraform and Github Actions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, terraform, github-actions

I have a simple little web application that consists of four docker containers with flask apps in them and a docker-compose file. They communicate via a message queue.
For starting the app locally, I simply use docker-compose up.
Then, all the web apps can be accessed via a gateway on localhost:5004.

Now I am trying to automate the deployment in the following way:

- Every time I push to the GitHub repo, a workflow via Github Actions is started
- This workflow connects to Terraform Cloud (specified in terraform.yml)
- Terraform creates a new AWS EC2 instance with port 5004 opened (specified in main.tf)
- And here comes the problem...

Locally, I would now

- copy the files to the EC2 machine with "scp -r -i *my_key*.pem *pathtoproject* ec2-user@*publicIP*:~/"
- ssh into the EC2 machine
- install docker and docker-compose
- do docker-compose up
- After that, I am able to access my app with *publicIP:5004*

How can I do that via Github Actions and Terraform?

I already tried the following:

- In main.tf: Use the user_data property of the EC2 machine for adding commands that should be executed after starting the machine. Problem here: I don't know how I can copy the files from the repository or clone the repository inside the EC2 machine. For copying, I would need the correct path (apparently, it is not simply the link to the file). For cloning, I would need to create a new SSH key inside the EC2 machine and add it manually to my github account - but since it should be automated, this is not a solution.
- Another option would be to use the public docker images of my containers - they are also being created by another Github Action. But still here, I have the same problem: I would have to somehow upload / copy / clone the docker-compose file to the EC2 machine.
- I also tried to do it directly via Github Actions and using Terraform solely for the creation of the machine, but since I am creating a new machine every time, also the IP address of the EC2 machine always changes. But I need that for ssh-ing in...

This is the repo: https://github.com/janakaras/docker-in-the-cloud

I hope I was able to describe the issue accurately, if not, I am sorry, I am new to all the CI/CD stuff :-).

Best regards and thanks,
Jana

Comment: I would first like to ask you to add the terraform code to the question. Second, if you are creating custom Docker images, you could use an ECR repository and then use the AWS CLI to pull the image or create an IAM role which would be assigned to the EC2 instance and then it would be able to pull the image from ECR.

Comment: Hi, this is the main.tf: 
https://github.com/janakaras/docker-in-the-cloud/blob/main/main.tf :-) 

Is there a possibility to do this via Github Actions or would I have to use my local commandline?

Comment: Ideally you would create a custom image with i.e. Packer that is provisioned with what you need. Then the `user_data` can execute Docker Compose and you are good to go. You could also use a container orchestration platform with your docker compose file and completely avoid dealing with almost all of this if you wanted.